# I created 3 buttons and if you click on any button the language of the website changes My javascript code works on local host but not on online server

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, google-translate

You can check the live server https://cannastech.in/projects/language/ here.

I created 3 buttons and if you click on any button the language of the website changes My javascript code works on local host but not on online server........................................................................................................................................................................................................................

````
<head id="Head1">
    <title>Google Translation</title>
<style>

.margin{
    margin: 40px 0;
}

.buttons{
    display: flex;
}

.button{
    margin: 1em;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color:#232B38;

}
.button{
    background-color: #232B38;
    padding: 1em;
}
.buttons li{
    list-style: none;
}
.button {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.button {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.button:hover{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.button:hover{
    color: #232B38;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.button span{
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="google_translate_element" style="display: none">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function googleTranslateElementInit() {
            new google.translate.TranslateElement({ pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, autoDisplay: false }, 'google_translate_element');
        }
    </script>
    <script src="http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function translateLanguage(lang) {

            var $frame = $('.goog-te-menu-frame:first');
            if (!$frame.size()) {
                alert("Error: Could not find Google translate frame.");
                return false;
            }
            $frame.contents().find('.goog-te-menu2-item span.text:contains(' + lang + ')').get(0).click();
            return false;
        }
    </script>
    <div class="margin">
    <ul class="buttons">

        <li><a class="button" href="javascript:;" id="Chinese" onclick="translateLanguage(this.id);"><span> Chinese</span></a> </li></button>
        
        <li><a class="button" href="javascript:;" id="Korean" onclick="translateLanguage(this.id);"><span> Korean</span></a> </li></button>
        
        <li><a class="button" href="javascript:;" id="Japanese" onclick="translateLanguage(this.id);"><span> Japanese</span></a> </li></button>
    </ul>
</div>
    <div>
        Hello
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: your server is https, your code tries to load scripts etc using http - do this `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>` ... and similarly for ALL the resources you try to load using `http`

Comment: Simply open your console, it's telling you what's wrong. `The page at 'https://cannastech.in/projects/language/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Comment: if you remove the `http:` from the urls that cause errors they will be loaded using the scheme from the host document - in your case `https`

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius so I just need to remove http from all links and it will work right?

Comment: That will, hopefully, prevent the errors but without testing your code it is hard to say whether or not that in itself will be enough to fix the issues. Alas the code you posted could not be tested - an error about the google frame I seem to remember

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have a website secured with an SSL certificate (the small lock infront of your URL) all the assets have to be from a secure location as well. That is even true for libraries you import from a third party like in your case jQuery.

So if the resource is provided with https as well, and jQuery is, just add https infront of your source and it will work like a charm.

Comment: it is. as long as you have reasonable CORS settings in your browser.

Comment: So if I just remove http from all links it will start working right?

Comment: yes - or even better replace http with https